# TensorFlow wrong array's shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm actually new to TensorFlow and ML in general and I'm trying to load a dataset from a pickle file. my data set is a list of 2 lists. The first list is 10 000 images each represented by an array of 3072 bytes. 1024 for each colors (rgb). The other list is 10 000 boolean value. I load my dataset like so:

```
X, Y = pickle.load(open('training_dataset.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Then I create my network using this code:

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3])
```

And get a `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (96, 3072) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 3)'`

How do I reshape my dataset to [?, 32, 32, 3]?
Is my pickle file not formated correctly?

This is the code used to create the pickle file:

```py
def unpickle(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as opened_file:
        data = pickle.load(opened_file, encoding='bytes')
    return data


def create_training_pkl_file():
    img_arrays_list = []
    is_bird_boolean_list = []
    training_dataset = []

    for i in range(1,6):
        batch = unpickle('./cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_' + str(i))
        for img in batch[b'data']:
            img_arrays_list.append(img)

        for label in batch[b'labels']:
            is_bird_boolean_list.append(label==2)

    training_dataset.append(img_arrays_list)
    training_dataset.append(is_bird_boolean_list)

    save_pickle(training_dataset, './training_dataset.pkl')
```

I'm using [CIFAR-10 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)

Comment: When you are reading data from the pickled filed, it has a shape of `(96,3072)`. Your pickled data is in wrong format. You need to `reshape` it to match with the input tensor

Comment: When I list the content of X, it gives me a list of 10 000 arrays of 3072 bytes, what would the 96 other values be?

Comment: `32x3=96`, so if I am right, you messed up somewhere in your code. Also, can you share your code where you are making this pickle file?

Comment: @Nain is right! It is the problem in your pickled dataset. I have to look into your pickled/unpickled dataset. Is it publicly available? If yes i can help you with this problem

Comment: @Saranns i've edited the post and added the code that creates my pickle file. All the info on the dataset should be in the link.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineGiguère Have you flatten the images before feed them into the network?

Comment: The CIFAR10 datasets are already python pickled. So once you do pickle.load() in function `unpickle()`and loop inside the file for each `img` you need to flatten `img` and transpose them as row vectors  (that agrees the number of neurons in the input layer) and then append it to list. You do not have to pickle them again as `save_pickle(training_dataset, './training_dataset.pkl')`.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineGiguère It is bit confusing to implement what i said in your code, so i update a piece of class that serve the best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple class that serve your problem the best. May look lengthy but quite easy to call them while executing the data flow graph.

`cwd = os.getcwd()   # Should be same as the directory where you extracted the CIFAR-10 dataset`

```
class DATA(cwd):
    def __init__(self, directory = "./"):
        self._directory = directory

        self._training_data = []
        self._training_labels = []       
        self._load_training_data()

        np.random.seed(0)
        samples_n = self._training_labels.shape[0]
        random_indices = np.random.choice(samples_n, samples_n // 10, 
                                          replace = False)
        np.random.seed()

        self._training_data = np.delete(self._training_data, random_indices, 
                                        axis = 0)
        self._training_labels = np.delete(self._training_labels, 
                                          random_indices)


    def _load_training_data(self):
        for i in range(1, 6):
            path = os.path.join(self._directory, "data_batch_" + str(i))
            with open(path, 'rb') as fd:
                cifar_data = pickle.load(fd, encoding = "bytes")
                imgs = cifar_data[b"data"].reshape([-1, 3, 32, 32]) #FLATTEN THE IMAGE
                # imgs are not 3d tensors anymore.
                imgs = imgs.transpose([0, 2, 3, 1]) # img tensors as row vectors # Resulting img.size() should equals number of neurons in the input layer.
                if i == 1:
                    self._training_data = imgs
                    self._training_labels = cifar_data[b"labels"]
                else:
                    self._training_data =np.concatenate([self._training_data, imgs], axis = 0)
                    self._training_labels = np.concatenate([self._training_labels, cifar_data[b"labels"]])

    def get_training_batch(self, batch_size):
        return self._get_batch(self._training_data, self._training_labels, batch_size)

    def _get_batch(self, data, labels, batch_size):
        samples_n = labels.shape[0]
        if batch_size <= 0:
            batch_size = samples_n

        random_indices = np.random.choice(samples_n, samples_n, replace = False)
        data = data[random_indices]
        labels = labels[random_indices]
        for i in range(samples_n // batch_size):
            on = i * batch_size
            off = on + batch_size
            yield data[on:off], labels[on:off]
```

Create an instance of the class DATA

`dataset = DATA()`

Get training data and its corresponding labels for a batch as

`training_data,training_labels = next(dataset.get_training_batch(batch_size))`

I am also in the learning curve as you, so if you need more detail about the code you can refer [here](https://github.com/tfteandcoffee/CNN)

Hope that helps!